# Karate: can we make multiple calls from scenario outline using an array variable?

Tags: arrays, karate, outline, scenarios

I have a sample array:

```
* def passwordData = ["abc", "abc2", "abc3", "abc4"]
```

And I have a scenario outline

```
Scenario Outline: xyz
      * someApiCall(username, password)
      Examples:
        | username | password        |
        |  admin   | #(passwordData) |
```

I want to send all the values of passwordData into examples one by one. what I want is, there should be 4 API calls based on 4 different sets of password data.
like,

```
set 1 - [admin, abc]
set 2 - [admin, abc2]
set 3 - [admin, abc3]
set 4 - [admin, abc4]
```

but currently, that's not happening, it is considering the whole password data in one and a comma-separated value is sent.

is there a way to achieve this in karate?

Comment: in addition to linked answer, note that functions can be used to generate a dynamic-scenario outline: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-function-data-source